# Image blurry on jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, image, mobile, blurry

I'm building out an area for an advertisement banner on jQuery Mobile and I'm running into an issue with the image appearing blurry when viewed on a smartphone (Android).

Is additional CSS required to fix this issue using jQuery Mobile or is it more an issue with the height/width of the image being displayed?

TEST AREA: [Ad banner testing with jQuery Mobile (link)](http://test.iowaassessors.com)

Comment: Search for "retina images"

Comment: It's not blurry for me at all - HTC One, Android 4.4.2, Chrome 34.  I assume you mean the advert at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Just a thought - you're not using a "turbo" type browser are you, that gives you the option to compress traffic (I know of Opera and Chrome offering it, but probably most of them do it by now).

Comment: I'm using the Chrome browser on Android 4.1.2, it's not terrible but it definitely looks blurry, I just tried working in a retina javascript and it didn't work

Comment: Yeah, that won't help - it's not even vaguely relevant.  Here's a screenshot.  I guess this looks fine? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BythFyyPSkqkOTd3ejItNjg5MFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you check your settings in Chrome?  Settings -> Bandwidth management -> Reduce data usage - make sure it's off

Comment: Just checked and it was turned off. Be sure to refresh the URL that I provided. I dropped in an image with a more fixed width/height that fits on a smartphone. Still showing up blurry.

Comment: It still looks okay to me.  It's not *as* sharp, but if you're resizing an image in the browser then that will happen.  It would be better if you used a larger image so that it's being reduced, rather than the other way round.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a shot. Would using the "width="100%" tag do the trick for that?

Comment: Yes, that's all you'd need as it will automatically resize the height to suit (constraining the ratio).

Comment: I've applied the width="100%" and it's still looking blurry. I'm wondering if this is just a retina issue that will persist on my version of Android or if I'm just applying this incorrectly.

Comment: UPDATE: Issue fixed. I was applying the wrong picture file. The width=100% addition completely fixed it. Thanks for the help Archer!